# Socket Synchronization - Java Client to MATLAB Server

Tags: java, sockets, networking, matlab

I have a system I am implementing where I have a MATLAB Server who uses a socket to accept a TCP connection, and a Java Client which connects to that server.

My problem is that when the server accepts the client's connection, apparently, the client manages to send the input before the server manages to reach a line of code that locks it into reading the expected input from the client...

Assuming I do not know how much time to wait would be safe, in a generic case, is there any way to solve this problem for all situations?

Could I use some sort of lock object, shared between MATLAB and Java? Should I assume that the client always awaits some sort of confirmation from the server? and if so, how exactly can i have a guarantee that the server will rush to listen after sending such a notification to the client, fast enough?

Thanks in advance!

By the way, if anyone knows of a simple way of getting the system time from Java (System.currentTimeMilis()) in MATLAB, it would be useful to further test this. I know there are quite some functions to access time in MATLAB, but I don't really know if there is any (or any way) to get it exactly the same way as in Java.

Comment: I do not have it handy anymore. This question had appeared as part of a relatively old project and I do not have the code handy anymore. In any case, it was marked as resolved with the solution from the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are easier ways to call Matlab from Java - JMI for example:
http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/jmi-java-to-matlab-interface/

Regarding the system time, run this in Matlab:

> javaTime = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis